# How to inject attributes into get_the_post_thumbnail?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I need to manipulate the `<img>` string returned by `get_the_post_thumbnail()`.

I know I can add the `$attr = "stuff here"`.

But how do I inject the source for the full size image into the one of the smaller sizes `('thumbnail', 'medium')` strings.

I get this (simplified):

```
<img src="url/to/thumbnail_image" />
```

And need to end up with this (simplified):

```
<img src="url/to/thumbnail_image" data-zoom-image="url/to/large/image" />
```

I've tried to inject the larger images source path by trying to concatenate strings ...

```
$large_image_url = the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' );

get_the_post_thumbnail( $the_post_id, 'medium', $attr = 'data-zoom-image=' . $large_image_url . '' );
```

But it gets stripped out. Anyone fought this before?

**NOTE:** I intentionally left out the wrapping quotation marks, as WP doubled them ... so that part of the output is working just fine.

Comment: `$attr` is an array of attributes, so you will need to pass your data to it as an array, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) (the one you're using `echo`'s the URL).

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $the_post_id, 'medium', [
    'data-zoom-image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $the_post_id, 'full' ),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, according to the documentation: string|array $attr = '' could be used. Obviously not. Unless it should be read as »an array of strings«. Query string or array ... hmm.

Comment: Your string version would also work with the `get_` function, I just find array syntax clearer.